# How to determine whether a site is HTTP or HTTPS?

Tags: html, http, https

How do you tell if a site is an HTTP:// site or an HTTPS:// site? I am just starting to learn some of the more fundamental things about internet security. When you put up a web site is there a special way that you have to set up the html format in the .html files so that the site is secure or is this something that can be purchased from the site provider were you host the web site.

This seems like and easy thing to do but even on stackoverflow what it type in is

```
    stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
```

There is no HTTP or HTTPS in front of the internet address. Is this implied or is there a way to toggle this on an off in the tools?

HTML Code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Test Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    //...code goes here...     
</body>
</html>
```

Is there something that goes in the HTML that determines whether the site is secure or not? Or is this an option on each page when you host the site.

Comment: If the URL has `http://` at the beginning, you are accessing it via HTTP. Likewise for `https://`.

Answer (score 6):

> How do you tell if a site is an HTTP:// site or an HTTPS:// site?

By looking at the URL

> This seems like and easy thing to do but even on stackoverflow what it type in is

If you type in something that looks like a URL with the scheme missing, then browsers will assume you intended to put `http://` in front of it.

Most browsers will hide the `http://` part from the address bar for non-SSL sites.

> When you put up a web site is there a special way that you have to set up the html format in the .html files so that the site is secure or is this something that can be purchased from the site provider were you host the web site.

To use SSL you need to have an SSL certificate and the web server needs to be configured to use it.

Beyond that, everything comes down to how the server is configured. You could have different sites hosted on http and https, or the same site, or redirect from one to the other, and so on.

> Is there something that goes in the HTML that determines whether the site is secure or not?

No. SSL is dealt with at the transport level, not the document level.

> Or is this an option on each page when you host the site.

You could configure a server to redirect the URLs for some pages to HTTPS and some to HTTP. This was typically done to save on CPU power for pages where security wasn't needed. Today, CPU power is much cheaper, so it is normally better to use SSL by default.

Comment: If you redirect a http site to an https site I would imagine that the redirection is then secure. When you host a web site I would imagine that this is an option. Should all pages be secured or only the ones that will be handling confidential information?

Comment: The initial request will be insecure, the response telling the browser to redirect will be insecure, the follow up request and response will be secure. See the last paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

To make a site secured (an HTTPS) site you need a certificate and add the proper binding that means including a port and protocol by default https uses port 443 and NO, none of those configurations at server level will affect the files serve like your .html files.

Comment: So you basically can put up any HTML file on a HTTPS site just as if you were putting them up on an unsecure HTTP site. Hate to ask, but what does the port and protocol basically do anyway. What if you switch the port to 500 will that affect the security of the site and how do you set or create the protocol?

Comment: A site can be both http and https. In the configuration you define for the http port 500 for example and for https you define the port 443 and you need to include a certificate for this last one.

Comment: Does the HTTPS port have to be 443? and then all of the unsure pages can be HTTP.

Comment: 443 is the default port same for HTTP with is port 80. The https is set at site level so this teams that all pages are either secured or non-secured it is not at file level

Answer (score 1):

HTTP means Hypertext Transfer Protocol. The "S" is **Secure**.

There is no special definition you can define to ensure a secure HTTP connection.

SSL (Secure Sockets Layer) is the standard security technology for establishing an encrypted link between a web server and a browser. This link ensures that all data passed between the web server and browsers remain private and integral.

These certificates can be purchased from companies that provide them. This essentially encrypts any data transferred between the server and person it is responding to.

Comment: The S is actually **with SSL**

Comment: @Quentin, are you saying that HTTPS means "HTTP with SSL"? As you mentioned in your answer above, SSL is at the transport level, but I understood http/https to be at the application level. Could you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

In short, this is determined by the browser, and different browsers have different strategies.

When you visit a site, such as [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com), different browsers will use different default protocols.

Microsoft Edge will first use http to connect to port 80 of the server. If the server is set to redirect, it will send a 301 move permanently message to allow the client to reconnect to the site using https.

But the new version of chrome will directly use https to connect to the site (port 443), if the connection fails, then connect to http (port 80).

https://blog.chromium.org/2021/03/a-safer-default-for-navigation-https.html

> Chrome will now default to HTTPS for most typed navigations that don’t specify a protocol. HTTPS is the more secure and most widely used scheme in Chrome on all major platforms. In addition to being a clear security and privacy improvement, this change improves the initial loading speed of sites that support HTTPS, since Chrome will connect directly to the HTTPS endpoint without needing to be redirected from http:// to https://. For sites that don’t yet support HTTPS, Chrome will fall back to HTTP when the HTTPS attempt fails (including when there are certificate errors, such as name mismatch or untrusted self-signed certificate, or connection errors, such as DNS resolution failure). This change is rolling out initially on Chrome Desktop and Chrome for Android in version 90, with a release for Chrome on iOS following soon after.